# How do I run jq on each log line and tail it?

Tags: bash, less, jq

I have a log file with each line being a json object. I want to view the log lines as pretty json while being able to tail the logs, with maybe `tail` or `less`.
I have tried the following and they either return immediately i.e. don't tail the logs, or appear to tail (by not returning) but don't update with new logs

```
less jsonlines.log | jq "." 
tail -f jsonlines.log | jq "."
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Works for me"™:

- in one terminal window:

  ```sh
  while true; do echo "{\"date\":\"$(date)\"}" >> logfile; sleep 1; done
  ```
- in another:

  ```sh
  tail -f logfile | jq .
  ```

Comment: you're right, it does work. Not sure why I thought otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: @sgarg - You might nevertheless want to use jq with the --unbuffered option.

Comment: @peak, this is a community wiki answer: you are encouraged to improve it.